# Determining If Left- or Right- Click

Tags: filemaker

In FileMaker Pro, it is easy to override a field's button setup so that a script is run when the field is clicked on. Is there a way from within such a script to determine if the user left-clicked or right-clicked?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly, I am pretty sure you can't get the mouse button clicked. If you could, it would probably be a Get() function.

I tested:

```
Get(ActiveModifierKeys)
```

and

```
Get(TriggerModifierKeys)
```

but neither return a value for mouse clicks, only keyboard clicks.

If you are a C++ programmer, you could write a plugin that creates a new FileMaker function that returns the mouse button clicked, but you would need to install the plugin on every machine that will use the function.